# Change tty remotely via SSH connection on a Mac

Tags: pi-4, ssh

On the RPI I have two sessions running on two different terminals (tty1 and tty2). from the Pi directly connected keyboard I can change between them using ALT + > keys and even `sudo cat /dev/vcs1` and `sudo cat /dev/vcs2` for a snapshot of what running.

When I remote in vis SSH I can change to different terminals with `[[ $(/usr/bin/tty) == "/dev/tty2" ]]` and subsequently view snapshot with `sudo cat /dev/vcs2`

Is there any way to login to say tty2 and view in real time the active terminal output?

Also when remote SSH via my Mac (Mac Keyboard) The ALT key in most cases is the OPTION key, but this doesn't seem to work to quickly switch between tty windows? some have suggested "control + Opt + F1-F6" but this also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Strictly this question is not Pi specific.

Have you tried tmux (a terminal multiplexer) in lieu. This allows you to switch between multiple programs and allows easy switching between them.

In practice I haven't used tmux for years; when I want another session I just open a new `ssh` session from my Mac.

Alternately openvt can open a virtual terminal (you need a few parameters e.g. -s to switch to the new vt; read man vt). I am not sure if this works over `ssh`